# Include caffee prototxt files in pyinstaller bundle

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, pyinstaller, caffe

I am trying to use pyinstaller to create an executable for a deep learning python application.

The application runs in a virtual env and uses tensorflow and opencv, I had a tone of problems with it which I resolved, but now I am stuck. It seems it is unable to read the deploy.prototxt file that the program uses

The error is:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1121: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "face_detector\deploy.prototxt" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromTextFile'

I included that file path in the spec file but no success.
My spec file is:

```
    block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['detect_mask_video.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Alexandru\\Envs\\deeplearning_covmask\\Lib\\site-packages', 'E:\\deeplearning\\apps\\face-mask-detector\\face-mask-detector'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\Alexandru\\Envs\\deeplearning_covmask\\Lib\\site-packages\\astor\\VERSION', 'astor\\VERSION' ),
             ('E:\\deeplearning\\apps\\face-mask-detector\\face-mask-detector\\face_detector\\deploy.prototxt','face_detector\\deploy.prototxt' )],
             hiddenimports=['tensorflow'],
             hookspath=['hooks'],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='detect_mask_video',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

How can i do to include the proto file in the resulted exe?

Comment: Did my answer help ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear in the documentation but from my experience with pyinstaller the destination has to be folder. In your spec file replace:

```
('E:\\deeplearning\\apps\\face-mask-detector\\face-mask-detector\\face_detector\\deploy.prototxt','face_detector\\deploy.prototxt' )
```

with

```
('E:\\deeplearning\\apps\\face-mask-detector\\face-mask-detector\\face_detector\\deploy.prototxt','face_detector' )
```